# php How to cache from web search for a pagination?

Tags: php, caching

One moment ago, I visted http://www.123people.com,  I am intersting in some technology from it.

After a web photo search. how to cache the data then for a pagination? In the raw code, I haven't see he load all the data in the page then make a jquery pagination with div show, hidden.

And I do not think, store into database is a good way.

Except these, How to cache from web search for a pagination?(A wise way, pay less server resource.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They can for example cache results as search "pages" [for example as files on hard drive], returning only information about current page and number of pages in collection. If data can change dynamically, they may store all the results in one place, and then "query" it for a specific subset of that data.

You have really many options to do that and probably quite much of them will be good / suffcicient.

Resources:

http://planetcakephp.org/aggregator/items/4559-pagination-caching-with-cakephp

http://www.web-design-talk.co.uk/210/php-paging-with-caching/

http://www.jotlab.com/2010/02/09/pagination-caching-with-cakephp/

http://stefanomanfredini.info/2010/09/single-query-cache-and-pagination-cache-until-a-future-post-and-ad-hoc-joins-an-over-override-of-appmodelfind/

google: php pagination cache

http://www.kattz.com/programming/20652-php-pagination-how-do-chnage-my-pagination-page-produce-static-pages-so-there-less-load-mysql-table.html

Apparently there are many resources with CakePHP in mind - I don't use it, but they'll show you the idea.

Comment: @Tomasz Kowalczyk, do u have some live examples? I am very intersting in it. I want to study. I think the difficult is how to creat unique `file` for each client? then how to know the client leave the line and then destroy this files automaticlly?

Comment: I don't have anything "live", but I can tell you that my answer covered only the "information cache" part, which will be usually achieved thorugh memcache or other memory storage. The crucial part is to build the website following REST idea, and then you can cache whole page or its fragments depending on the parameters it'll be given. So it goes down to the idea that a next search page with the same query is another request to the server with LIMIT clause incremented by 10 [number of items on a page], no more, no less.

Comment: @Tomasz Kowalczyk, thanks for answer, I think it is difficult for me as my skill is not well. Any way, would u like to give me some key words so that I can search in google for a good understanding.

Comment: Thanks. May be I shall set a username :}

Comment: Definitely - if you want to be recognized, the best way is to use your name and surname. Especially when you have the knowledge and want to share it. People tend to like those who go out in front of them.